# How to get string from gson in HashMap<String,Object> which is represented below

Tags: java, android, json, gson

Can't get string from json object. I get

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Map<String, Object> resultMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
resultMap = (Map<String, Object>)gson.fromJson(result, resultMap.getClass());
if (handler!=null) {
   handler.responseReceived(new HashMap(resultMap),_queryName);
}
```

and in another class I need to get Elements of JsonObject

```
public void responseReceived(HashMap<String, Object> resp, String action) {
    Log.e("!!!", action);
    Log.e("!!!", "--------");
    Log.e("!!!", resp.toString());
    //Json Parsed, need just to get elements of jsonobject
}
```

Now how to get String, elements from `HashMap<String,Object>` resp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can print the values with your current code.

Use  map.keySet().toString()  to print the String values from map 
or if you want to print the Objects use map.values().toString()

Checkout the example below for more details,

Created a small object class Employee

```
package com.zack.demo;

public class Employee {

    private String name;

    private int age;

    private String gender;


    public Employee(String name, int age, String gender)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.gender = gender;

    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

}
```

The GSONTest class has different input and output formats which can print values from Map

```
package com.zack.demo;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class GsonTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Gson gson = new Gson();

        Map<String, Object> resultMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        Employee o1 = new Employee("Test1", 10, "Male");

        resultMap.put("T1", o1);

        Employee o2 = new Employee("Test2", 20, "Male");

        resultMap.put("T2", o2);

        String result = gson.toJson(resultMap, resultMap.getClass());

        System.out.println(result);

        Map<String, Object> resultOutputMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        resultOutputMap = (Map<String, Object>) gson.fromJson(result,
                resultOutputMap.getClass());

        System.out.println("Complete Map: "+ resultOutputMap.toString());

        System.out.println("Values: "+resultOutputMap.values().toString());

        System.out.println("Keys: "+resultOutputMap.keySet().toString());

    }

}
```

Output from the above class

```
{"T1":{"name":"Test1","age":10,"gender":"Male"},"T2":{"name":"Test2","age":20,"gender":"Male"}}
Complete Map: {T1={name=Test1, age=10.0, gender=Male}, T2={name=Test2, age=20.0, gender=Male}}
Values: [{name=Test1, age=10.0, gender=Male}, {name=Test2, age=20.0, gender=Male}]
Keys: [T1, T2]
```